# Node.js Express wildcard (catch-all) won't work on App root

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I am not using any any template engine. 
I want to redirect everything to my static file /public/desktop.html

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

function route(req, res, next) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/desktop.html');
    myURL = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
}
```

It works well if I use this and access 'localhost:8080/anypath on the url

But if I try 'localhost:8080/' I get nothing:

```
app.get('*', route);
```

And I can't access anything if I use any of those:

```
app.get('/', route);
app.get('/*', route);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')) is mounting a static file handler that is turning the '/' into '/index.html' and sending a 404 because it can't find index.html

If you change the ordering around:

```
function route(req, res, next) {
  if(req.url!='/'){
    return next();
  }
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/desktop.html');
}

app.get('/', route);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

It might work?

Comment: actually it solved but caused another issue function route(){...} now reads all css and js files on my /public outputing a error for the external js

Comment: Hey - I've updated the example so it filters any request not for the '/' url